# git server synchronises with svn server

Tags: git, svn

I have a git server and a svn server. I want to synchronize code committed on either server to another server, e.g., I commit code to git server, and then I can also get the same code from a svn server that synchronizes the code from git server.

I find that *git-svn* can commit code that is controlled by git to a svn server, but it seems no help concerning my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling this and found [git-svn-mirror](http://git-svn-mirror%20%20A%20command-line%20tool%20that%20automates%20the%20task%20of%20creating%20a%20GIT%20mirror%20for%20a%20SVN%20repo,%20and%20keeping%20it%20up-to-date.):

> A command-line tool that automates the task of creating a GIT mirror
>   for a SVN repo, and keeping it up-to-date.